# Index a SQL Server table for searching on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table with 15 columns - all of type int, nvarchar or datetime.  I want to be able to find rows that match values in 6 of the nvarchar columns and 1 of the datetime columns.  A stored procedure will do the select and return the rows.  My question is how should I create an index so the select will be optimal?  One index on 7 columns or 7 separate indexes on each column?  Does it matter?  Does the order of WHERE clauses in the select matter to the order of indexed columns?

**edit**

It may help to know that the purpose of the select is to find 1 or 0 records.  The 6 columns are needed to define a unique record and the datetime column is used to find that record in the past X days.

**edit 2**

Currently, there is no data in the table.  The purpose of the table is to determine whether certain action has been performed for a certain client.  Before each action, I will look for a record in the table with those 7 column values.  If there is no record, I will perform the action and then insert a record.  If there is a record, I will skip to the next action and repeat the process.

Given that there will be lots of inserts to this table the indexes will be rebuilding frequently.

Thanks!

Comment: Run the queries you have against that table get explain plans for them.  From that find out where indexes will help. You have to test a few different sceneries with composite indexes and indexes with just a single value in them to get the best performance.  You may want to consider a covered index depending on your usage as well.  Pretty much comes down to "it depends".

Comment: How unique are the values in these columns?

Comment: How do I get the explain plan and how do I use that to find out where indexes will help?
None of the values in the columns will be unique, that's why I need to use 6 columns to find a unique record.

Comment: In SSMS you can click "Query" ---> "Include Actual Execution Plan" before you run your query. (Ctrl+M) is they keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2: Since you clarified your question I can give a more specific answer.

You want one index with the six columns included.

I'm still a bit confused regarding the datetime column. You say that the six columns define unique entries. If they are unique for the whole table you need the datetime value neither in the index nor in the query. If they are unique only for a given date, you need to include it in both the index (total of seven columns) and the query.

The six/seven-column index is probably not feasible as a clustered index (especially if you want to create other indexes as well), so if you don't have a clustered index already, create one, preferably on an auto-id-column. A clustered index should be as small as possible, unique and always rising, because it affects the way in which the table and the other indexes are stored.

The six/seven-column index should be marked as unique and not contain any additional columns. If possible, the columns should be ordered in a way that the index produces rising values on each insert, because that will limit or in the best case eliminate fragmentation, thus increasing I/O performance.

Based on your description this is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: So 1 index with multiple columns is better than 7 indexes with 1 column?  Also - I can't try different variations because at present there is no data in the table.

Comment: If you have uniqueness or even near-uniqenuess with a combination of columns and you include these columns in the where-clause to get zero or one row, then yes, a combined index is definitely much better than one index per column.

Comment: @Matthew - If it adequately covers your criteria, a single covering index is a good idea.  Bear in mind **your index fields need to be in the same order as in the where clause**, and it may behoove you to put an `INCLUDE` for any fields not in the where clause that  you want the query to return.

Comment: @JNK: I have no idea what RDBMS you are talking about, but in SQL-Server the order of columns in the where-clause has no effect at all. Included columns is a feature from SQL 2005 and upwards. If they are appropriate or not depends mainly on the size of the returned columns. The larger they are, the less feasible it is to include them. If you return all columns from a table you are effectively creating another clustered index, which is in general not a very good idea. The OP only wants to check whether a given set of values is in the table, hence doesn't need included columns.

Comment: @TToni - I am referring to SQL Server, and the order of the items in the `WHERE` clause vs the index **does** matter.  I mentioned the included column to avoid a bookmark/key lookup if he only wants one or two values from the table.

Comment: @TToni - point taken about the OPs request though to only check for the existence of the columns.

Comment: @JNK: Though I found this link (http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/04/looking-under-hood.html) regarding order of things in the where clause, I still hold that with a simple where, in which you check the value of columns without invoking subqueries or hidden joins, the order in which the columns appear has absolutely no effect whatsoever. The query optimizer is definitely intelligent enough to use the correct index in these cases.

Comment: @TToni - it is and it isnt :)  The other thing to consider is if you have a covering index on `Col1, Col2, Col3` and your `WHERE` clause is on `Col1, Col3, Col2, Col4` I don't think it will be used at all...

Comment: @JNK: Of course it will be used, if it makes sense to the optimizer. Including the Col4 makes the use more expensive, if the index is not clustered, because it requires an additional lookup, so there will be cases in which your statement is true. But you seem to say that the optimizer can only find indexes when the columns in the WHERE are exactly like the index and that is very very wrong.

Comment: @TToni - You should try this then on a test table, I think you will be surprised at the result.

Comment: @JNK, @TToni -- The 6 columns define uniqueness for a record but the datetime column is there because I only care if the record exists in the last x days. I will be returning the whole record so does that mean I need to put `INCLUDE` on all the other columns?  What does it do?

Comment: @Matthew - Depends on the size of all the other columns.  You probably don't want to include them all.  `INCLUDE` basically means once the index has been used to find the right row, it doesn't need to go back to the clustered index page for whatever fields you put into `INCLUDE` - they are in the leaf level of the index.  If it's a LOT then it's a waste of space and you will have to settle for a Key lookup, which refers back to the clustered index for the missing values

Comment: @JNK: So I did check it on a table with some 20.000 rows and of course the index is used. No surprise there at all.